# Gaining muscle/strength while losing weight

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, muscle-gain, vegetarian

TLDR: What can I do at gym wise, the gym is Planet Fitness, and nutrition wise to gain strength and muscle and also lose weight?

I'm 17, going to be 18 in August, and I've wanted to be muscular and strong for a while. I was obese for most of my life, and I recently lost about 70 pounds in about a year and a half, going from 220 to 150. I'm an athlete, I play cricket, so I also want to get fitter and stronger for that. I used to rely on calisthenics as exercise, since I'd had very little time to devote to going to the gym. I'd gone from zero pushups to about 30 in a set. Can't do a pull up yet though. I'd gone to my gym, Planet Fitness, for about 3 months earlier this year when my schedule cleared up, from January to March, for 3 times a week each week. I had noticed increases in strength, but nothing for increase in size. Recently, I've started going to the gym again and working out with the weight machines and I have noticed the increase in strength again, but again nothing in terms of size gain. I've heard from friends that to build muscle I need to do 4 sets of 10 reps, other sources say 3 sets of 8 reps, other friends say to go high weight and low rep to train for strength and my muscles will get big. As a general rule, I do no cardio other than when I play cricket, since I've heard that cardio hampers any gains. But again, I've seen no mass gain at all. As you can see, I'm very confused about all this.

Nutrition wise, I'm a vegetarian, so most of my protein comes from dairy, soy, and protein shakes. I try to get 1 gram per pound of body weight on workout days, but I'm scared that I'll be putting on more fat than anything. I make sure to get protein in at least 2 hours after a workout, and I spread my protein out through my meals.

In general, I would appreciate any and all help offered here. I'd been obese and fat for my whole life until just recently, and I'd always dreamed of one day being strong and muscular. I'm hoping that this is my chance to do it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you boil this all down to one question? This is very broad right now.

Comment: Edited with a TLDR at the top!